# How to let users login with Twitter AND Facebook (Firebase/Firefeed)

Tags: twitter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am working with the Firefeed app (based on Firebase) and I am wondering how I can give users the option to both login with Facebook and Twitter.

I correctly set-up my firebase but I guess the issue is that I either use

```
authClient.login("facebook");
```

or

```
authClient.login("twitter");
```

How can use both to give them the choice? I know, its probably a beginner questions. :)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for here. If you want to allow people to log in with either option, then you can simply have 2 buttons, one that says "Log in with Twitter" and one that says "Log in with Facebook".

If you want to have an account system that merges multiple social accounts into a single account on your system, so that users could log in with either system and access the same data, this is a little more complex. There's a thorough answer here:
[How can I login with multiple social services with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148089/how-can-i-auth-with-multiple-social-services-with-firebase/15148259#15148259)

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrew! I basically want to have an account system that merges multiple social accounts. I had a look at the link you posted and it seems like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help!