# Does Firebase create accounts for all authentication types?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Email registrations are seen as a new record under the **Simple Login** → **Email** tab in our forge.

But what happens when a user *Signs In* using one of the OAuth2 logins like Facebook or Google?

Take the [example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html) right off the site and apply multiple contexts to it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "comments": {
      "$comment": {
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".validate": "auth.id == newData.child('userid').val() && newData.hasChildren(['userid', 'body']) && newData.child('body').isString()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- If a user logs in with a Facebook account will Firebase create a new `auth` record and scope security rules in the same context as an Email/Password login?
- If so are those registrations viewable in the same way as our Email auth type? Do you perform operations on those records like (delete) in the same way?
- What would be the best way to scheme a master userId collection that enables a user to tie multiple account types together? *(Facebook, Google, and Email all tied together)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that "creating a user" in that console (and in Firebase Simple Loign email / password auth. in general) only generates a new mapping between an email address and a password, and gives that account a unique, auto-incrementing id.

Firebase Simple Login will not automatically store any data in your Firebase, though upon login, it will automatically generate a new Firebase auth. token against which you may write security rules making use of the `auth` variable.

Login methods using any other provider currently store no data, though in the future there may be more functionality there. Logging in with Facebook / Google / etc. will also fetch a bunch of useful user metadata and send it down to the client, in addition to creating a Firebase auth. token for use in security rules. To see the contents of the `auth` variable across all providers, see the 'After Authenticating' section on each of the Simple Login Providers docs pages, for example: [Facebook](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-facebook.html). There is no notion of a delete for any provider except for the email / password provider.

If you'd like to have user accounts that are linked to multiple social credentials, it can be done, though it is a little clunky (and manual) at present. See [How can I login with multiple social services with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148089/how-can-i-login-with-multiple-social-services-with-firebase/15148259#15148259) for a thorough walkthrough.

Comment: So if an auth token was generated for a Facebook login - the `auth.id` would be the same after logging in again... This would allow you to have a mixture of login types (different users) scoped to the same collection rules right?

Comment: @DanKanze Correct! Also note that there is a `uid` parameter on the auth token, that looks like '<provider>:<id>', which allows you to store all user accounts in one list without fear of collisions between providers.

Comment: Are any two `uid` every going to be the same? For example could I make the `uid` the key name in a `users` collection?

Comment: The `uid` will never be the same for two different users. This `uid` attribute is specifically intended for the use case you describe, and is safe to use. =)

Comment: I have a few questions about that strategy you linked me to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886053/can-the-firebase-auth-object-handle-simultaneous-authentication-types